# corebluetooth: iOS discovers characteristics I'm not asking for

Tags: core-bluetooth

I call `[CBeripheral discoverCharacteristics:forService:]` with a list of characteristics I'm looking for.

The `[CBPeripheralDelegate CBPeripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:]` callback seems to return all characteristics that the device advertises for this service, not just the ones I'm asking for.

What am I missing about discovering characteristics?

Answer (score 0):

That method will return all characteristics for the service. It depends on the hardware you're using and which services/characteristics the hardware has.

For example, the CC2540 keyfob device only has 9 services and 25 characteristics. Although there are many more services/characteristics that could be used with the BLE architecture, those are the only ones that can be used with the CC2540 device. It is possible to add characteristics onto a hardware device using the IAR workbench.

Comment: Your answer adds nothing. My starting point is the observation that CB reports all characteristics of a service on a device, regardless of the argument array of UUIDs. My surprise is at having an argument that that seems to have no function. Oh, and welcome to SO. You must be new here, or I'd downvote your answer.